# Getting 'Could not find or load main class' error for mvn --version after installing Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have just installed Maven, set up the environment variables M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME, JAVA_HOME is set correctly to point to the JDK on my machine.
But When I execute the command `mvn --version` I get the following error (means `Could not find or load main class =`).
[image]

`where mvn` and `where java` show where maven and java executables are. The version of Maven I'm using is 3.8.6, My JDK version is jdk1.8.0_181.

What could be the problem in my case ?

Comment: The environment variables `M2_HOME` nor `MAVEN_HOME` do mean something special. What you need to enhance is the `PATH` variable in your system. You should enhance that with the directory where you have unpacked the apache maven zip file and add that location pluse `bin` in your PATH variable.

Comment: @khmarbaise I did add %M2_HOME%\bin to PATH variable